# Как скопировать определённые значения из dataframe в одну строчку list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape((25,4)))
      
list_ = []

list_[0] = dataframe['0'][0:20]
```

В данном случае значения будут записаны, как объект `pandas series`.
Мне же нужно чтобы `20` этих значений были представлены в строчном формате, указанные к примеру через пробел.

Есть ли простой способ это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `join()` с предварительным преобразованием чисел в строки или `pandas.Series.cat()`

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape((25, 4)))
print(' '.join(map(str, dataframe[0][0:20].tolist())))
# или
print(' '.join(dataframe[0][0:20].astype(str).tolist()))
# или
print(dataframe[0][0:20].astype(str).str.cat(sep=' '))

# поместим в список
list_ = [dataframe[0][0:20].astype(str).str.cat(sep=' ')]
print(list_[0])
```

```
0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76
0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76
0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76
0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76
```

Answer (score 1):

У DataFrame и Series существует метод to_list. Пример кода:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['foo', 'bar', 'guido', 'python']})
n = df['NAME'][0:2].to_list()

print(n) # ['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Я подправил тему чтобы было понятней. Нужен строчный формат. В коде выше  получается лист в листе.